# Slide div 100% right to left? CSS-JQUERY

Tags: jquery, css

I need to slide a div menu 100% width when page loads. but it is not working:

css

```
#menu{
 position: fixed;
 z-index: 101;
 top:0;
 color:#fff;
 font-weight:bold;
 font-size: 10px;
 height:50px;
 width:100%;
 min-width:50px;
 background:red;
}
```

JQUERY

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#menu").animate({ left: '0'}, 'fast');
});
```

what I want is this div, when page loads, starts appear on the right corner till left and stay on the top with 100% width after that.
http://jsfiddle.net/12tx42q4/

thank you

Comment: You can only slide elements within the Menu Div sideways since the Menu itself is 100% wide

Comment: You are moving it by 0, so offcourse nothing happens. Guessing this is what you want? http://jsfiddle.net/12tx42q4/7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give it a starting point like `left: 100%`: [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/12tx42q4/8/)

`left: 0` is the default starting point, so without changing that, its not going to appear to animate.

Answer (score 1):

you just have to set `left:100%`

http://jsfiddle.net/12tx42q4/5/

Answer (score 0):

You are basically saying: When the body is loaded slide to left with a distance of 0 pixels.

Try setting the amount of pixels it must travel

> Left: 'Insert pixels here'

Like this:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
          $("#menu").animate({ left: '100'}, 'slow');
  });
```